# Get correct percent in dimplejs vertical 100% bar chart

Tags: dimple.js

I have created a vertical 100% bar chart similar to this [example](http://dimplejs.org/examples_viewer.html?id=bars_vertical_stacked_100pct) but with the Titanic dataset. The default tooltip shows the correct percentages but my modified tooltip does not. In the figure below, the tooltip should show 73%, which is the percentage of women that survived, instead of 100%. [image]

It seems that my code is giving me the correct percent as it is aggregating with respect to the variable Sex instead of along the dimension of Survived/Did not survive. Code snippets below. Variable 'source' is defined by clicking on the menu.

```
d3.tsv("data/titanic.tsv", function(data) {

    var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
    var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", source); 
    x.addOrderRule(source);
    var y = myChart.addPctAxis("y", "count");
    var mySeries = myChart.addSeries(["Survived"], dimple.plot.bar);
```

And for the tooltip:

```
    mySeries.addEventHandler("mouseover", function (e) {
      var cx = parseFloat(e.selectedShape.attr("x"));
      var cxWidth = parseFloat(e.selectedShape.attr("width"));
      var cy = parseFloat(e.selectedShape.attr("y"));

      // set size and coordinates of tooltip
      var width = 120;
      var height = 50;
      var xPop = (cx +width + 10 < svg.attr("width")) ? cx: cx ;
      var yPop = (cy - height / 2 < 0) ? 25: cy - height / 2 + 35;

      popup = svg.append("g");

      // change style of tooltip
      popup
          .append("rect")
          .attr("x", xPop + 5)
          .attr("y", yPop - 5)
          .attr("width", 150)
          .attr("height", height)
          .attr("width", width)
          .attr("rx", 5)
          .attr("ry", 5)
          .style("fill", "white")
          .style("stroke", "#36b0b6")
          .style("stroke-width", 2);

      //add appropriate text to tooltip
      popup
        .append('text')
        .attr('x', xPop + 10)
        .attr('y', yPop + 10)
        .append('tspan')
        .attr('x', xPop + 10)
        .attr('y', yPop + 20)
        .text(e.seriesValue[0])
        .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
        .style("font-size", 10)
        .append('tspan')
        .attr('x', xPop + 10)
        .attr('y', yPop + 40)
        .text("Percent: " + d3.format(",.0f")(e.yValue *100))
        .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
        .style("font-size", 10);
   });
```

With acknowledgements to [Anna Pawlicka](http://annapawlicka.com/pretty-charts-with-dimple-js/) for original tooltip code. I have played around with `yValue`, `seriesValue`, and `aggField`. I can get the correct percent to show up by hard coding via something like

```
if (e.xValue==="Female" && e.seriesValue[0]==="Survived") {
           var t = 337/464 }
```

but that is not the most elegant solution.

Any ideas on what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you've done it makes sense, but there's an oversight in the eventArgs which causes it to send the running total rather than the total for the segment.  You can work around it by applying the event handler with the d3 method.  It's important that you move the code after the draw function is called, at which point you can get access to the d3 shapes and apply an event handler with on:

```
// Must draw first
myChart.draw();

// Can now access series.shapes for d3 stuff
mySeries.shapes.on("mouseover", function (d) {

    // d contains the full data element as used by dimple's internal methods
    var cx = parseFloat(e.selectedShape.attr("x"));
    var cxWidth = parseFloat(e.selectedShape.attr("width"));
    var cy = parseFloat(e.selectedShape.attr("y"));

    // set size and coordinates of tooltip
    var width = 120;
    var height = 50;
    var xPop = (cx +width + 10 < svg.attr("width")) ? cx: cx ;
    var yPop = (cy - height / 2 < 0) ? 25: cy - height / 2 + 35;

    popup = svg.append("g");

    // change style of tooltip
    popup
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", xPop + 5)
        .attr("y", yPop - 5)
        .attr("width", 150)
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("rx", 5)
        .attr("ry", 5)
        .style("fill", "white")
        .style("stroke", "#36b0b6")
        .style("stroke-width", 2);

    //add appropriate text to tooltip
    popup
        .append('text')
        .attr('x', xPop + 10)
        .attr('y', yPop + 10)
        .append('tspan')
        .attr('x', xPop + 10)
        .attr('y', yPop + 20)
        .text(e.seriesValue[0])
        .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
        .style("font-size", 10)
        .append('tspan')
        .attr('x', xPop + 10)
        .attr('y', yPop + 40)

         // Now you just need to use height instead of yValue
        .text("Percent: " + d3.format("%")(e.height))

        .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
        .style("font-size", 10);
  });
```

The code is the same as yours apart from using `on` instead of `addEventHandler` and using `height` instead of `yValue`.

Comment: Thanks, almost there. I can get the correct % now using `d.height` and the correct text using `d.aggField[0]`. Having trouble with the code for `cx` and `cy` so tooltip always in same spot. Tried `d.x` and `d.y` but that doesn't seem to work. Is that info buried in the `d` object somewhere?

Comment: x and y are logical so you could convert them with the scale objects or get them from 'this'. Try d3.select(this).attr("x") and same for y (or any shape attribute).